Column inside SingleChildScrollView with variable height widget
I know it's notoriously tricky to put a Column inside a SingleChildScrollView, especially if there are expanded widgets in the column.
I'm in a weird situation where I'm trying to build a form. In this form, there is a chip bar (aka tag bar). When the user types text inside this bar, a ListView of suggestions opens up below the bar. It opens vertically. But the layout of the form is messed up by this extra height. If the screen is short (or if the form is long), I'm getting all sorts of problem (the ListView of suggestions doesn't show, exceptions, etc). See in the picture below, the list of suggestions is partly masked and can't be used.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var scaffold = Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('Test layout')),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                child: buildForm(context))));

    return scaffold;
  }

I believe this is because I use maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height for the box constraints. If I use maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 2, the ListView of suggestions is not masked anymore, but the page of the form ends up being unnecessarily long, and when the listview is opened, there is large gap between the tag bar and the next field. I tried playing with the coefficient of the maxHeight, but I feel it's hackish and could easily break depending on the length of the suggestions in the tag bar. I feel I'd need something that adapts to the length of the tag bar + the list of suggestions. Would you have any idea to improve my layout please?. Here is a reproducible example:
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  final EditableChipField _tagBar = EditableChipField();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var scaffold = Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('Test layout')),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 2,
                    minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                child: buildForm(context))));

    return scaffold;
  }

  Widget buildForm(BuildContext context) {
    return FormBuilder(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(children: [
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              FormBuilderTextField(
                  name: 'name'),
              Flexible(fit: FlexFit.loose, child: _tagBar),
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              FormBuilderTextField(
                  name: 'other'),
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              Row(children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("Cancel"),
                  onPressed: () {},
                )),
                const SizedBox(width: 20),
                Expanded(
                    child: FilledButton(
                        child: Text("OK"), onPressed: () {})),
              ]),
            ])));
  }
}

const List<String> _pizzaToppings = <String>[
  'Olives',
  'Tomato',
  'Cheese',
  'Pepperoni',
  'Bacon',
  'Onion',
  'Jalapeno',
  'Mushrooms',
  'Pineapple',
];

class EditableChipField extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> chips = <String>[];

  EditableChipField({super.key});

  @override
  EditableChipFieldState createState() {
    return EditableChipFieldState();
  }
}

class EditableChipFieldState extends State<EditableChipField> {
  final FocusNode _chipFocusNode = FocusNode();
  List<String> _suggestions = <String>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        ChipsInput<String>(
          values: widget.chips,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.local_pizza_rounded),
            hintText: 'Search for toppings',
          ),
          strutStyle: const StrutStyle(fontSize: 15),
          onChanged: _onChanged,
          onSubmitted: _onSubmitted,
          chipBuilder: _chipBuilder,
          onTextChanged: _onSearchChanged,
        ),
        if (_suggestions.isNotEmpty)
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.loose,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _suggestions.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ChipSuggestion(
                  _suggestions[index],
                  onTap: _selectSuggestion,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onSearchChanged(String value) async {
    final List<String> results = await _suggestionCallback(value);
    setState(() {
      _suggestions = results
          .where((String chip) => !widget.chips.contains(chip))
          .toList();
    });
  }

  Widget _chipBuilder(BuildContext context, String chip) {
    return ChipInputChip(
      chip: chip,
      onDeleted: _onChipDeleted,
      onSelected: _onChipTapped,
    );
  }

  void _selectSuggestion(String chip) {
    setState(() {
      widget.chips.add(chip);
      _suggestions = <String>[];
    });
  }

  void _onChipTapped(String chip) {}

  void _onChipDeleted(String chip) {
    setState(() {
      widget.chips.remove(chip);
      _suggestions = <String>[];
    });
  }

  void _onSubmitted(String text) {
    if (text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        widget.chips = <String>[...widget.chips, text.trim()];
      });
    } else {
      _chipFocusNode.unfocus();
      setState(() {
        widget.chips = <String>[];
      });
    }
  }

  void _onChanged(List<String> data) {
    setState(() {
      widget.chips = data;
    });
  }

  FutureOr<List<String>> _suggestionCallback(String text) {
    if (text.isNotEmpty) {
      return _pizzaToppings.where((String chip) {
        return chip.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase());
      }).toList();
    }
    return const <String>[];
  }
}

class ChipsInput<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChipsInput({
    super.key,
    required this.values,
    this.decoration = const InputDecoration(),
    this.style,
    this.strutStyle,
    required this.chipBuilder,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.onChipTapped,
    this.onSubmitted,
    this.onTextChanged,
  });

  final List<T> values;
  final InputDecoration decoration;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final StrutStyle? strutStyle;

  final ValueChanged<List<T>> onChanged;
  final ValueChanged<T>? onChipTapped;
  final ValueChanged<String>? onSubmitted;
  final ValueChanged<String>? onTextChanged;

  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T data) chipBuilder;

  @override
  ChipsInputState<T> createState() => ChipsInputState<T>();
}

class ChipsInputState<T> extends State<ChipsInput<T>> {
  @visibleForTesting
  late final ChipsInputEditingController<T> controller;

  String _previousText = '';
  TextSelection? _previousSelection;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = ChipsInputEditingController<T>(
      <T>[...widget.values],
      widget.chipBuilder,
    );
    controller.addListener(_textListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(_textListener);
    controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  void _textListener() {
    final String currentText = controller.text;

    if (_previousSelection != null) {
      final int currentNumber = countReplacements(currentText);
      final int previousNumber = countReplacements(_previousText);

      final int cursorEnd = _previousSelection!.extentOffset;
      final int cursorStart = _previousSelection!.baseOffset;

      final List<T> values = <T>[...widget.values];

      // If the current number and the previous number of replacements are different, then
      // the user has deleted the InputChip using the keyboard. In this case, we trigger
      // the onChanged callback. We need to be sure also that the current number of
      // replacements is different from the input chip to avoid double-deletion.
      if (currentNumber < previousNumber && currentNumber != values.length) {
        if (cursorStart == cursorEnd) {
          values.removeRange(cursorStart - 1, cursorEnd);
        } else {
          if (cursorStart > cursorEnd) {
            values.removeRange(cursorEnd, cursorStart);
          } else {
            values.removeRange(cursorStart, cursorEnd);
          }
        }
        widget.onChanged(values);
      }
    }

    _previousText = currentText;
    _previousSelection = controller.selection;
  }

  static int countReplacements(String text) {
    return text.codeUnits
        .where(
            (int u) => u == ChipsInputEditingController.kObjectReplacementChar)
        .length;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.updateValues(<T>[...widget.values]);

    return TextField(
      minLines: 1,
      maxLines: 3,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      style: widget.style,
      strutStyle: widget.strutStyle,
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          hintText: 'Add tags'),
      onChanged: (String value) =>
          widget.onTextChanged?.call(controller.textWithoutReplacements),
      onSubmitted: (String value) =>
          widget.onSubmitted?.call(controller.textWithoutReplacements),
    );
  }
}

class ChipsInputEditingController<T> extends TextEditingController {
  ChipsInputEditingController(this.values, this.chipBuilder)
      : super(
          text: String.fromCharCode(kObjectReplacementChar) * values.length,
        );

  // This constant character acts as a placeholder in the TextField text value.
  // There will be one character for each of the InputChip displayed.
  static const int kObjectReplacementChar = 0xFFFE;

  List<T> values;

  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T data) chipBuilder;

  /// Called whenever chip is either added or removed
  /// from the outside the context of the text field.
  void updateValues(List<T> values) {
    if (values.length != this.values.length) {
      final String char = String.fromCharCode(kObjectReplacementChar);
      final int length = values.length;
      value = TextEditingValue(
        text: char * length,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: length),
      );
      this.values = values;
    }
  }

  String get textWithoutReplacements {
    final String char = String.fromCharCode(kObjectReplacementChar);
    return text.replaceAll(RegExp(char), '');
  }

  String get textWithReplacements => text;

  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan(
      {required BuildContext context,
      TextStyle? style,
      required bool withComposing}) {
    final Iterable<WidgetSpan> chipWidgets =
        values.map((T v) => WidgetSpan(child: chipBuilder(context, v)));

    return TextSpan(
      style: style,
      children: <InlineSpan>[
        ...chipWidgets,
        if (textWithoutReplacements.isNotEmpty)
          TextSpan(text: textWithoutReplacements)
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ChipSuggestion extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChipSuggestion(this.chip, {super.key, this.onTap});

  final String chip;
  final ValueChanged<String>? onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      key: ObjectKey(chip),
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text(
          chip[0].toUpperCase(),
        ),
      ),
      title: Text(chip),
      onTap: () => onTap?.call(chip),
    );
  }
}

class ChipInputChip extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChipInputChip({
    super.key,
    required this.chip,
    required this.onDeleted,
    required this.onSelected,
  });

  final String chip;
  final ValueChanged<String> onDeleted;
  final ValueChanged<String> onSelected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 3),
      child: InputChip(
        key: ObjectKey(chip),
        label: Text(chip),
        avatar: CircleAvatar(
          child: Text(chip[0].toUpperCase()),
        ),
        onDeleted: () => onDeleted(chip),
        onSelected: (bool value) => onSelected(chip),
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I took a quick look, i think that part of widget causes a problem:
You are nesting a ListView inside a SingleChildScrollView
 if (_suggestions.isNotEmpty)
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.loose,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _suggestions.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ChipSuggestion(
                  _suggestions[index],
                  onTap: _selectSuggestion,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),

Try to set shrinkWrap : true and physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to that list view.
Some Enhancements:

It's preferable to check the behavior of your widget with and without
those Flexible, i noticed two Flexibles.(if it's working it's ok)

You can remove the ConstrainedBox from the SingleChildScrollView if
its purpose to make the SingleChldScrollView allocate the whole
screen.


and follow this structure:
Column(
 Expanded(
  SingleChildScrollView(.....)
 )
 )

Old Advice: be careful while you are inside a scroll view.

Explanation
Any ScrollView widget is a special kind of widgets that offer an infinity of space, so while you are dealing with that kind of widgets don't use greedy widgets inside it.
The term greedy widgets refers to any widget that will allocate all of the available space like (Flexible or Expanded).
If you wanna to imagine, answer this question: How can you allocate all of the available space, if that space is infinite? you can't.
But, what if that scroll view is nesting another one inside it.
Again, If you wanna need to imagine, answer this questions:
How can you scroll the nested widget while it's inside another scrollable widget?
Which one will be scrolled?
In fact, it's logically wrong to have nested scrollable widgets specially if they have the same scroll direction. Scroll control must be granted to the outer scrollable widget and the inner widget scrolling behavior must be deactivated.
Hence, while you are touching the inner scrollable widget and swipes it up or down the whole scrollable widget (outer + inner) scrolls.
That was about the NeverScrollableScrollPhyscis , what about shrinkWrap : true.
when it's set to true, means that this scroll widget will take as much as it fits.
Note: Scrollable widgets desire to expand (take what's available), most of widgets actually do.
Remember : you can't takes what's available while you are inside a scroll view, it's infinity. Got it?
I think the remaining to explain is the ConstrainedBox :
It's a good practice to impose constraints on widgets, but constraints must be reasonable and logical.
To reach the dimensions of the screen, you usually use MediaQuery.of(context).size.
So, height represents the height of the screen in pixels, maxHeight in constraints is set to screenHeight * 2.
How can the widget occupy twice the height of the screen, don't get confused. we are now out of the scroll view 'SingleChildScrollView'.
Imagine that scroll view is a container, how the container height become twice of the screen height. it can't.
So, the purpose of the constraints mainly is to let that SingleChildScrollView to allocate the whole screen? remember the greedy widgets?
That's why we wrapped it with an Expanded widget.
One More rule : Those greedy widgets must have a parent widget of type (Row , Column or Flex) it's a rule.
After that long typing, I hope it's sufficient to get you on the right road.
Hope it helps you.

Thanks, shrinkWrap : true + physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() + removing the flexibles + removing the ConstrainedBox worked. I'll accept your answer, but could explain why it solves my problem please?

Perfect, thanks so much for the additional information, it definitely helps.
